# How to create a new image from existing docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file that has 3rd party application which downloads models from internet when build the docker image.

*Docker file:*

```
FROM my-third-party-address
# add arguments
# run commands
ENTRYPOINT["/run-application.sh"]
```

When I build and run this dockerfile, it downloads models and puts the image directory.

I execute the "docker build" and push the image in a pipeline. And when I run the application on kubernetes, the image downloads the images again.

I want to create a new image from builded and stored models in. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a multi-stage build.

Stage one is your third part image, you run the model download in it, stage two you copy the results into a new image.

https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/